# Where is the documentation of 'module' method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Whenever you define a new module you call the method `module`:

```
module A
...
end
```

I've looked for it in https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/ but I didn't find it. Where is it?

Comment: see [Module.new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-c-new) I think the `module A .. end` syntax is syntactic sugar for doing this and assigning it to a constant in one go.

Comment: `module` is one of Ruby's [keywords](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/keywords_rdoc.html). See also the introduction to [Module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html).

Answer (score 3):

The `module` keyword is exactly that: a keyword, not a method. Since this is part of Ruby's language syntax it is not documented along with defined classes and their methods, but in its syntax documentation at

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Modules

Comment: Very interesting. So, just curious. Where does Ruby store what IS and what IS NOT keywords? I knew that 'something' was going on, as I couldn't find the doc, but I didn't think of that (kind of obvious however :)). Thank you!

Comment: @borjagvo Keywords are listed in [keywords.rdoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/keywords_rdoc.html), as mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64378371/1301972).

Answer (score 2):

### Module is Both a Keyword and an Object

While `module` is certainly a defined [Ruby keyword](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/keywords_rdoc.html), the underlying implementation is more complex. Pragmatically, a [Module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Module.html) is a class-like [Object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Object.html) that serves as the parent class of [Class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Class.html). It provides namespacing, and offers some additional features for mixin and module/class composition.

AFAICT, the syntax for creating a Module definition (rather than instantiating it) is handled by the [RACC](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/_lib/racc/rdoc/grammar_en_rdoc.html) grammar, so if you’re looking for implementation details you may want to explore RACC, Ripper, and other interpreter elements to determine *how* the keyword actually implements the module definition.